# Windows Server 2003 (with IIS6) + VPN Connection

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, iis-6, port

I have configured Windows Server 2003 and it servers web-pages just fine.

But as soon as I use my server to establish a VPN connection (using the new connection wizard) to another server I receive "connection has timed out" on my clients when I try to access the web-pages.

I tried using both ip-numbers (ISP and VPN ip's). The other end of the vpn have all the ports open. I've turned off all firewalls. I'm able to surf the web just fine via the VPN connection.

I am able to access the web-pages from my server using the vpn-ip but only on the server itself.

Any ideas on how I can have both the VPN-connection and still serve web-pages? Does not have to be through the vpn, the isp is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Windows pptp VPN client? By default, it routes all traffic through the tunnel to the remote gateway.

However, you can make a quick adjustment to it to no longer use that remote gateway.  Edit the VPN connection properties. Go to the Networking tab (odds are you can go ahead and disable IPv6 while there) and then edit propertied for the IPv4 protocol. Hit “Advanced” and then uncheck “Use default gateway on remote network.”

Now only the traffic intended for the other end of the VPN will go that route. Everything else will go using your own gateway. I think this will solve your issue.